# Remove fork on github apiary

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

Is there a way to remove the fork on github from apiary? I've tried targeting the css classes with display none. It still shows on the page.

```
.row.tocColumnTool.forkOnGitHub{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the settings. By setting the repository to private, it will remove the fork on GitHub. [image]